# How to display the info message like in image

Tags: ios5, ios4

How to display the message **"Which accounts will benefit the most from these best practices? Think,add customer names and supercharge yourself!"**  like popup display?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a pop-up in the iOS SDK, you'll want:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
            message: @"Which accounts will benefit the most from these best practices? Think,add customer names and supercharge yourself!"
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];

// Show the popup  
[alert show];
```

For one that has the message you specified, and the button title of "OK" to dismiss it, and the title "Announcement".

Comment: thanks for reply, i need to display popup like in sms preview. tel me Tom

Comment: 1) You're not being very clear - please clearly define what you want 2) "tel me Tom" - manners go a long way